# Using button push to update tkinter label (help for a homebrew RPG)

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I'm trying to build a simple tkinter UI that both displays the attributes of a simple RPG character and allows the player to update those attributes for a homebrew RPG. I have gone through a lot of the answers to similar questions but I'm missing something (probably obvious) and my buttons don't change the UI.

I am doing this little project as a follow on from finishing python crash course (which was really helpful) but this one has me stumped.

I have tested the functions in a separate script and the do what I want, but when I try to make them work within the UI nothing happens, no error or traceback, just no change to the UI either.

I'm sorry I think some of the indentations in the longer lines might be wrong in this example but I promise it's good in the actual script. I have made a separate module called character that contains the Character class and the functions associated. As I said above, they work fine when I just run that script but they don't affect the UI (even though they import fine and don't cause any errors).

```
    from tkinter import LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER, X, Y, SUNKEN
    import tkinter as tk
    from character import Character



    class GlobalFrequency:
        """The overall class for the app"""
        def __init__(self, master):
            """intialise the attributes of the variable"""
            self.master = master
            master.title = "Global Frequency"


    #trying to set this up with a character
            self.character = Character('Miranda zero')

            self.name_label = tk.Label(master, text = 
                                       self.character.name.title(),         
                                       font=("Helvetica", 20))
            self.name_label.pack()

    #This is where the buttons and stuff start, 
            self.str_frame = tk.Frame(master, width=400)#strength frame
            self.str_frame.pack(fill=X)
     #This is the only button with a function so far
            self.st_btn_1 = tk.Button(self.str_frame, text = 'Strength 
                                      up', font=("System", 16), 
                                      command = lambda: 
                            self.character.increase_attribute('strength'))
            self.st_btn_1.pack(side = LEFT)
     #This is a second button, not assigned a function yet
            self.st_btn_2 = tk.Button(self.str_frame, text = 'Strength 
                                      down', font=("System", 16))
            self.st_btn_2.pack(side = LEFT)

            self.str_label = tk.Label(self.str_frame)
            self.str_label.configure(
                               text=self.character.attributes['Strength'],
                              font=("System", 16))
            self.str_label.pack()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x600")
    gui = GlobalFrequency(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

What should happen when self.st_btn_1 is pressed is that the label next to it should update to say:

```
    Strenght: 2
```

As I've said, when I just run the function outside of the tkinter code the character attribute does update but it just doesn't effect the UI.

I'm sorry if this question is really stupid, or if my code is shoddy, but I'm trying to learn by doing.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your label to a [tk variable](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) that can raise events and update when it's value is changed. In your code you set the label text value to a constant string. Use something like the example below with a `tk.IntVar` or `tk.StringVar`

```
import tkinter as tk

def increment(var):
    var.set(var.get() + 1)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    value = tk.IntVar()
    label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=value, width=10, anchor=tk.W)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Increment", command=lambda: increment(value))
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
    button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer, however I don't really understand the answer. I've set the label to print the value of a particular attribute which is stored in a dictionary in my Character class, so I need to convert this value into and IntVar somewhere in my tkinter code?

Comment: No Ignore that last comment, it worked! I had to go and edit my other script but it did indeed work, or at least it mostly worked. 

Thanks a million.